# Remembering where bricks are placed on html 5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, collision-detection

I am trying to make my first html5 canvas game and so far have come up with this, you can use left, right and down arrow keys.

You can see the code here,

http://jsfiddle.net/ShaShads/EWC5B/

I thought about using some sort of array and a grid but I don't really know if it would work?

```
var someArray = [];
```

Then use the array to store the blocks but for collision detecting I don't really know!

I have hit a bump and have no idea on how to start having the bricks stay on the screen once they reach the bottom and for the collision of bricks afterwards to be remembered so that bricks can stack? I am not asking for a give me all answer some pointers into what I could research to help me get there will be enough, and thanks.

It is my first game so if there are many errors then please tell me so I can improve, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bottom of Screen

To test if the object is at the bottom of the screen it's just a simple test:

```
If obj.y >= (canvas.height - object.height) then don't increase obj y position.
```

### Box Stacking

To get your boxes to stack, on each loop you need to check if a particular box collides with another box:

```
for (var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
    var boxA = boxes[i];

    for (var j=0; j<boxes.length; j++) {
        var boxB = boxes[j];

        if (boxA collides with boxB) don't increase boxA y position 
    }
}
```

Do note that this is very inefficient but will suffice for your first game. For a more efficient method, try this [link](http://buildnewgames.com/broad-phase-collision-detection/).

---

So that's pretty much the theory behind it. How to do this? Well you can make your life much  easier if you have a good way to manage your boxes.

For example, you could have a box object that has an x and y position as well as it's height and width. You can also give it a isMoving property which will be used to determine if the box is stack/on the floor or still in motion.

This method is pretty much the equivalent of "Remembering" as each box object keeps track of it's own position.

Store these box objects in an array so you can easily iterate over your boxes.

Comment: Thank you very much I can now build off of this! I will post another js fiddle when I have tried to implement it, thanks again!